# Obfuscator.XT encrypted my Outlook.pst

Tags: microsoft-outlook, encryption, virus, trojan, decryption

A trojan named `Obfuscator.XT` encrypted my Outlook.pst file (Outlook 2003) to a file named `locked-Outlook.pst.oldv` in the same directory.

What can I do to decrypt the file?

Comment: I need to find a reference signature. What antivirus gave you this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a program that unlocks encrypted files from trojans. It was not designed for that particular trojan but worked.

It can be downloaded [here](http://www.bitfox24.de/service/tools/scareuncrypt.zip?1) (ScareUncrypt) and does NOT need a reference unencrypted file to generate a key.

By the way there were a lot more files encrypted than just the Outlook.pst.